# pass class variable by reference in an arg

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to do the following;

```
var myVar;  

function testFunction(args){  
args.cacheVar = new Date();  
}  

testFunction({cacheVar:myVar});
```

but instead of changing the value of myVar, its changing the value of args.cacheVar.
What I would like to happen is for myVar = new Date(). not args.cacheVar.

How can I accomplish this with my current setup? (using arguments)

Comment: Do you mean changing the object's `cacheVar` property from `myVar` to `new Date()`? or do you mean changing the value of the variable `myVar` and giving it `new Date()`? And why does it have to be through the `arguments`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing `myVar` to your function.  You are passing an object.  That object may get updated, but since you do not have a reference to it anywhere, nothing happens.

You need to save your object as a variable before passing it.

```
var myVar = {cacheVar:null}; 

function testFunction(args){  
    args.cacheVar = new Date();  
}  

testFunction(myVar);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're passing a reference to `testFunction` all right, but it's a reference to an object literal you've created on the fly: `testFunction({cacheVar:myVar});`<-- `{}` is the object that is referenced. It's never assigned to any variable, so it's GC'ed as soon as `testFunction` returns.
The `cacheVar` property is assigned *a copy of `myVar`'s value* (undefined in this case). You must remember that only *objects* are passed by reference `typeof something` will return `object` for arrays, object literals, custom objects, functions... but can return `undefined`, `string`, `boolean` and `number` which are all primitives. `null` is the exception that proves this rule BTW (it returns `object` for historical reasons).

If you want to change the value of `myVar`, just use `myVar`:

```
function testFunction()
{
    myVar = new Date();
}
//alternative:
function testFunction()
{
    return new Date();
}
var myVar = testFunction();
```

The first way, however, is not very safe (implied globals), so either return the desired value directly to the variable you'd like to change (second version), use closures or turn everything into an object, but that might just take us too far right now